# Perl HTML::HeadParser, and regex results printed to one file

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, printing

I have a script that interrogates one folder with several HTML files and parses them looking for certain headers and uses a regex to extract additional info.  Results are printed to one CSV file.  I can't seem to get the second array piece and printing right.  I've tried several modification of the current script and I'm stuck.  I'm good at java and html but quite green when it comes to perl.  Guidance and help are appreciated. Thx Laurie!

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTML::HeadParser;
use Text::CSV;

# config
my $dfile  = 'all_tags.csv';
my $dir    = 'Test';
my @TAGS = ('Content-Base', 'Title', 
            'X-Meta-author', 'X-Meta-description', 
            'X-Meta-keywords', 'X-Meta-name',);

my @TAGS2 = ('color', 'red', 
            'politics', 'Dr.', 
            'Ph.D', 'M.D.',
            'called', 'rejection',
            'debt', 'hurt',
            'chaser', 'joke',
            'fork', 'heart',
            'face', 'chicken',
            'me', 'X',
            'imagine'
            );  



# output
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/});
open my $fh1, ">:encoding(utf8)", $dfile 
    or die "Error opening $dfile: $!";
$csv->print($fh1,['Filename',@TAGS]); # parser header

my $string = quotemeta @TAGS2;
while ( my $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) { 
$string->print($fh1, ['Filename',@TAGS2]);# regex header
     }

# input              
find ({wanted =>\&HTML_Files, no_chdir => 1}, $dir);
close $fh1 or die "Error closing $dfile: $!";
exit;

sub HTML_Files {
  parse_HTML_Header($File::Find::name) if /\.html?$/;
}

sub parse_HTML_Header {

  my $ifile = shift;
  print "parsing $ifile\n";

  open my $fh0, '<', $ifile or die "Error opening $ifile: $!\n";
  my $text = do{ local $/; <$fh0> };
  close $fh0;

  my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
  my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
  $p->parse($text);

  my @cols = map{ $h->header($_) }@TAGS;
  $csv->print($fh1, [$ifile,@cols]);
  my @cols2 = map{ $h->$string($_) }@TAGS2;
  $string->print($fh1, [$ifile,@cols2]);

  #my $string = quotemeta 'awarded';
  #while ( $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) { 
  #print $fh1 $1,"\n";
#    }

 }
```

Here are some examples of my html input, expected output and errors I see in terminal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.15), see www.w3.org">

  <title>Aberdeen%20Genetic%20purity , News Search |
  Ask.com</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http:/">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=
  "http://www.">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href=
  "http://www.">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href=
  "http://www">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href=
  "http://www.">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href=
  "http://www.">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <style type="text/css">
#midblock,#rightblock,#mobile-footer,.mobile-web-results,.hcsa,.footer {
  visibility:visible !important;
  }
  </style>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=
  "/st/c/css/ask_news.min.1fbfe92a.css">
  <style type="text/css">
.hcsa {
  visibility:hidden;
  }
  .sprite {
  background-image: url(http://);
  }
  .news-top-video-arrow{
  background-image: url(http://);
  }
  @media
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .sprite {
  background-image: url(http://);
  background-size: 111px 181px;
  }
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

Here's an example of my output:

```
Filename    Content-Base    Title    X-Meta-author    X-Meta-description    X-Meta-keywords    X-Meta-name
Test/1.html    Aberdeen%20Animal%20trait%20analysis , News Search | Ask.com
```

I'm trying to get the regex results to print above after the last entry X-Meta-name. If I use the follow code instead of the array that I'm using:

```
my $string = quotemeta 'CEO';
 while ( $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) {    
    print $fh1 $1, ",";
}
```

I can get the following

```
Test/Ames_Animal trait analysis.html.result.txt_parsed_for_news.txt.html    Ames Animal trait analysis , News Search | Ask.com                        
Test/Ames_Biobank.html.result.txt_parsed_for_clinic.txt.html                            
both adults and infants. Dr. Kocher has requested who    hrough a separate study. Dr. Lazaridis' samples     alon    colon and rectal cancer. Dr. Nelson has requested sto    rointestinal microbiome. Dr. Nelson and her colleague    in a new research study. Dr. Ames is recruiting parti    ers.</p>    
<p>In addition     Dr. Thibodeau has expanded t    sh; who have PKD.</p>                    
<p>Dr. Harris' goal is to bette    h another study.                        
</p>                            
<p>Dr. Heit has also asked for     ients who've had a clot. Dr. Heit's goal is to identi     To study microvesicles     Dr. Jayachandran is requesti    pice caregivers.            
</p>                            
<p>Dr. Kaur is researching whet    18">Nilufer Taner     M.D.     Ph.D.</a>     is studying geneti    0027660">Janet E. Olson     Ph.D.</a>     and <a href="http:
Test/Ames_Biobank.html.result.txt_parsed_for_jobs.txt.html                            
ompany-overview/hamilton-awards">Awards</a></li>                            
    <l    Test/Ames_Biobank.html.result.txt_parsed_for_news.txt.html    Ames Biobank , News Search | Ask.com                    
Test/Ames_Biorepository.html.result.txt_parsed_for_news.txt.html    Ames%2520Biorepository , News Search | Ask.com
```

but as you can see I have spacing and formatting issues as I'm trying to get 1 row per file with all items from that file listed on that 1 line

I can certainly copy this:

```
my $string = quotemeta 'CEO';
while ( $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) {    
    print $fh1 $1, ",";
}
```

20 times and replace the $string value with what I'm looking for but that seems like an inelegant and wasteful way as I should be able to do it in an array

I've modified my code to the following

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTML::HeadParser;
use Text::CSV;

# config
my $dfile  = 'all_tags.csv';
my $dir    = 'Test';
my @TAGS = ('Content-Base', 'Title', 
            'X-Meta-author', 'X-Meta-description', 
            'X-Meta-keywords', 'X-Meta-name',);

my @TAGS2 = ('CEO', 'founder', 
            'professor', 'Dr.', 
            'Ph.D', 'M.D.',
            'company called', 'startup called',
            'joins', 'receives funding',
            'SBIR', 'receiving the grant',
            'seed investment', 'seed fund',
            'appointed', 'chosen',
            'secures', 'award',
            'seed investment', 'awarded',
            );    



# output
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/});
open my $fh1, ">:encoding(utf8)", $dfile 
    or die "Error opening $dfile: $!";
$csv->print($fh1,['Filename',@TAGS]); # parser header

my $string = map {quotemeta} @TAGS2;
#my $text = 
while ( my $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) {    
$string->print($fh1, ['Filename',@TAGS2]);# regex header
     }

# input              
find ({wanted =>\&HTML_Files, no_chdir => 1}, $dir);
close $fh1 or die "Error closing $dfile: $!";
exit;

sub HTML_Files {
  parse_HTML_Header($File::Find::name) if /\.html?$/;
}

sub parse_HTML_Header {

  my $ifile = shift;
  print "parsing $ifile\n";

  open my $fh0, '<', $ifile or die "Error opening $ifile: $!\n";
  my $text = do{ local $/; <$fh0> };
  close $fh0;

  my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
  my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
  $p->parse($text);

  my @cols = map{ $h->header($_) }@TAGS;
  $csv->print($fh1, [$ifile,@cols]);
  my @cols2 = map{ $h->$string($_) }@TAGS2;
  $string->print($fh1, [$ifile,@cols2]);

  #my $string = quotemeta 'awarded';
  #while ( $text =~ m/ ( .{0,25} $string.{0,25} ) /gisx ) {    
  #print $fh1 $1,"\n";
#     }

 }
```

and get the following errors

```
Use of uninitialized value $text in pattern match (m//) at header_parser12.pl line 38.
parsing Test/1.html
Can't locate object method "20" via package "HTTP::Headers" at header_parser12.pl line 66.
```

Please find a cleaned up and debugged version of my script below:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTML::HeadParser;
use Text::CSV;

# config
my $dfile  = 'all_tags.csv';
my $dir    = 'Test';
my @TAGS = ('Content-Base', 'Title', 
            'X-Meta-author', 'X-Meta-description', 
            'X-Meta-keywords', 'X-Meta-name',);

# match words            
my @WORDS = qw( CEO founder professor Dr. Ph.D M.D. company called startup called joins receives funding SBIR receiving the grant seed investment seed fund appointed chosen secures award seed investment awarded );

my $words =  join '|',map { quotemeta } @WORDS ;
my $regex = qr/.{0,25} (?:$words) .{0,25}/;

# output
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({eol => $/});
open my $fh1, ">:encoding(utf8)", $dfile 
    or die "Error opening $dfile: $!";
$csv->print($fh1,['Search Words',@WORDS]); # header
$csv->print($fh1,['Filename',@TAGS,'Search Results']); # header

# input              
find ({wanted =>\&HTML_Files, no_chdir => 1}, $dir);
close $fh1 or die "Error closing $dfile: $!";
exit;

sub HTML_Files {
  parse_HTML_Header($File::Find::name) if /\.html?$/;
}

sub parse_HTML_Header {

  my $ifile = shift;
  print "parsing $ifile\n";

  open my $fh0, '<', $ifile or die "Error opening $ifile: $!\n";
  my $text = do{ local $/; <$fh0> };
  close $fh0;

  my @matches = ($text =~ /($regex)/gisx);
  #print join "\n",@matches;

  my $h = HTTP::Headers->new;
  my $p = HTML::HeadParser->new($h);
  $p->parse($text);

  my @cols = map{ $h->header($_) || '' }@TAGS;
  $csv->print($fh1, [$ifile,@cols,@matches]);

}
```

---

I did some research and figured out that the lotame info returned was actually in the html files.  Here's the section that was extracted from:

```
</script> <script>
/**
* Trigger the backfill event with lotame params
* @param lotameInfo
* @returns no return
*/
var logBackfillEvent = function (lotameInfo) {
setTimeout(function () {
if (typeof _Anemone === "object") {
payload = {};
payload.pl_ltmedata = {};
payload.presentation = {"count": 0};
payload.provider = {};
payload.pl_bfj = JSON.stringify(payload);
payload.pl_ltmedata = lotameInfo;
payload.pl_ltmedata = JSON.stringify(lotameInfo);
payload['anxi'] = JSUtil.defaultVal(_AnemoneParams2.eventId, '');
_Anemone.logEvent('BackFill', payload);
}
}, 0);
}
/**
* Read the lotame cookie
* If lotame cookie not exist then make a request for the Lotame Audience Extraction async call
* Drop the lotame cookie
* Trigger the backfill with lotame params
* @param e
* @param t
* @param id
*/
```

I'm not sure why the above values were returned as I don't see any keywords in there.  Maybe something is close enough that it's pulling it.  I'll have to take a closer look.  Maybe I need to do an exact match.  I also am still having trouble on search for two words at a time.  I'll keep trying.  Any insight you have would be greatly appreciated. Thanks - Laurie.

Comment: You will need to show what your current code produces and what the required result is

Comment: I've gone back and added input file, expected results, current results, modified code after some work, and current errors.

Comment: Thank you, that's excellent. Are the initial `+` signs continuation lines or are they actually in the data?

Comment: Continuation lines I'd imagine I'm not sure.  I copied both sets of results from csv files that were output that I opened in excel on a mac.

Comment: Okay it's still very unclear what it is you're trying to do. For instance you call `$string->print()` which doesn't do anything useful. What do you mean by that? Also, the code that you show prints 25 characters either side of every occurrence of `CEO`, and the output is all in the *body* of the HTML. But you only show the `<head>` element and that is all that you've parsed. Can you show what result you actually want from that HTML input please? It would also be nice if you explained the purpose of `@TAGS2`

Comment: I've modified the post above to include a newer version of the script.  The script now runs without errors on my side and the formatting is better, 1 row per file with comma separated values. But I don't seem to be getting the key words from the regex search that I'm looking for and instead get some code like items that start with an "*" that I can't figure out: Test/Boulder_Personalized medicine.html.result.txt_parsed_for_news.txt.html Boulder%2520Personalized%2520medicine , News Search | Ask.com * Trigger the backfill event with lotam * Read the lotame cookie t then make a request for the Lo

Comment: second part of comments - * Drop the lotame cookie * Trigger the backfill with lotame para //Setting the cookie.raw to true to avo id the encoding I tried a google search on "* Trigger the backfill event with lotam" and the other phrases and I'm stumped. Also how can I use multiple words here:

    # match words            
    my @WORDS = qw( press founder professor Dr. Ph.D M.D
          called receives joins timing find two 
          self bottom true amazing forget night next day );

Comment: The desired output is 1 csv file that contains one line with the parsed results from each html files in the Test folder.  Here are the headers from my output file: Filename Content-Base Title X-Meta-author X-Meta-description X-Meta-keywords X-Meta-name Search Results CEO founder professor Dr. Ph.D M.D. company called startup called joins 'receives funding' SBIR receiving the grant seed  investment seed fund  appointed chosen secures award seed investment awarded

Comment: Please see end of question above for more details and results of latest troubleshooting.

Comment: Please edit your question to include lengthy details. They're generally unreadable in comments. At this point I suggest that it may be best to open a new question and incorporate all the information tidily. You need to show an entire HTML file, which you can put on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and link to if it's too big to insert into a question